# Push rejected, fails Python App to Heroku

Tags: heroku

Iam pushing my python app to heroku and it failed at dependencies, it shows error that Rust packet manager is not installed, but it is installed on my pc.

All Depedencies went fine, but at the end, iam getting error, here is log

```
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 1.09 KiB | 1.09 MiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> No Python version was specified. Using the buildpack default: python-3.9.5
remote:        To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing python-3.9.5
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.2.4, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.36.2
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting anyio==2.2.0
remote:          Downloading anyio-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
remote:        Collecting argon2-cffi==20.1.0
remote:          Downloading argon2_cffi-20.1.0-cp35-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (97 kB)
remote:        Collecting async-generator==1.10
remote:          Downloading async_generator-1.10-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
remote:        Collecting attrs==20.3.0
remote:          Downloading attrs-20.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (49 kB)
remote:        Collecting Babel==2.9.1
remote:          Downloading Babel-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.8 MB)
remote:        Collecting backcall==0.2.0
remote:          Downloading backcall-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
remote:        Collecting bleach==3.3.0
remote:          Downloading bleach-3.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (283 kB)
remote:        Collecting certifi==2020.12.5
remote:          Downloading certifi-2020.12.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)
remote:        Collecting cffi==1.14.5
remote:          Downloading cffi-1.14.5-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (406 kB)
remote:        Collecting chardet==4.0.0
remote:          Downloading chardet-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
remote:        Collecting colorama==0.4.4
remote:          Downloading colorama-0.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
remote:        Collecting comtypes==1.1.10
remote:          Downloading comtypes-1.1.10.tar.gz (145 kB)
remote:        Collecting decorator==5.0.7
remote:          Downloading decorator-5.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (8.8 kB)
remote:        Collecting defusedxml==0.7.1
remote:          Downloading defusedxml-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
remote:        Collecting deprecation==2.1.0
remote:          Downloading deprecation-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
remote:        Collecting entrypoints==0.3
remote:          Downloading entrypoints-0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
remote:        Collecting idna==2.10
remote:          Downloading idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
remote:        Collecting ipykernel==5.5.3
remote:          Downloading ipykernel-5.5.3-py3-none-any.whl (120 kB)
remote:        Collecting ipython==7.23.0
remote:          Downloading ipython-7.23.0-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
remote:        Collecting ipython-genutils==0.2.0
remote:          Downloading ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
remote:        Collecting jedi==0.18.0
remote:          Downloading jedi-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)
remote:        Collecting Jinja2==2.11.3
remote:          Downloading Jinja2-2.11.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
remote:        Collecting json5==0.9.5
remote:          Downloading json5-0.9.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
remote:        Collecting jsonschema==3.2.0
remote:          Downloading jsonschema-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
remote:        Collecting MarkupSafe==1.1.1
remote:          Downloading MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (32 kB)
remote:        Collecting matplotlib-inline==0.1.2
remote:          Downloading matplotlib_inline-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
remote:        Collecting mistune==0.8.4
remote:          Downloading mistune-0.8.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
remote:        Collecting nbclassic==0.2.7
remote:          Downloading nbclassic-0.2.7-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
remote:        Collecting nbclient==0.5.3
remote:          Downloading nbclient-0.5.3-py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
remote:        Collecting nbconvert==6.0.7
remote:          Downloading nbconvert-6.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (552 kB)
remote:        Collecting nbformat==5.1.3
remote:          Downloading nbformat-5.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
remote:        Collecting nest-asyncio==1.5.1
remote:          Downloading nest_asyncio-1.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (5.0 kB)
remote:        Collecting notebook==6.3.0
remote:          Downloading notebook-6.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (9.5 MB)
remote:        Collecting packaging==20.9
remote:          Downloading packaging-20.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
remote:        Collecting parso==0.8.2
remote:          Downloading parso-0.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
remote:        Collecting pickleshare==0.7.5
remote:          Downloading pickleshare-0.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9 kB)
remote:        Collecting prometheus-client==0.10.1
remote:          Downloading prometheus_client-0.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (55 kB)
remote:        Collecting prompt-toolkit==3.0.18
remote:          Downloading prompt_toolkit-3.0.18-py3-none-any.whl (367 kB)
remote:        Collecting pycparser==2.20
remote:          Downloading pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
remote:        Collecting Pygments==2.9.0
remote:          Downloading Pygments-2.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.0 MB)
remote:        Collecting pyparsing==2.4.7
remote:          Downloading pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
remote:        Collecting pypiwin32==223
remote:          Downloading pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 kB)
remote:        Collecting pyrsistent==0.17.3
remote:          Downloading pyrsistent-0.17.3.tar.gz (106 kB)
remote:        Collecting python-dateutil==2.8.1
remote:          Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
remote:        Collecting pytz==2021.1
remote:          Downloading pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
remote:        Collecting pywinpty==1.0.1
remote:          Downloading pywinpty-1.0.1.tar.gz (47 kB)
remote:          Installing build dependencies: started
remote:          Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Getting requirements to build wheel: started
remote:          Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
remote:            Preparing wheel metadata: started
remote:            Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
remote:            ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
remote:             command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpr_08fbxd
remote:                 cwd: /tmp/pip-install-0_jtyszs/pywinpty
remote:            Complete output (6 lines):
remote:            Checking for Rust toolchain...
remote:
remote:            Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.
remote:            This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through
remote:            the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/
remote:
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpr_08fbxd Check the logs for full command output.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to isgd-requests-app.
```

I didnt get where is the exact error, I do reinstall of rust packet manager, but still the error shows, Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The log says you need to install Cargo.

Comment: Cargo is installed, but it still shows the same

Comment: You don't need to install Rust and Cargo on *your* machine. You need to install them on *Heroku*, via dependencies. In any case this is not a Git or Python issue.

Comment: Yes, heroku is already installed, but still iam getting the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rust` dependency is bring by [pywinpty](https://pypi.org/project/pywinpty) that needs also MSVC.
This package

> PyWinpty allows creating and communicating with Windows processes that
> receive input and print outputs via console input and output pipes.
> PyWinpty supports both the native ConPTY interface and the previous,
> fallback winpty library.

Then it is not needed on stack [heroku-20](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-20-stack) that is Ubuntu.

Removing `pywinpty` from `requirements.txt` should help.

Comment: @sunny9495 So maybe needed to provide what detect the rust buildpack, however it is quite strange to install `pywinpty` on heroku, maybe simpler to not install it ? The [doc](https://pypi.org/project/pywinpty/) also says it needs MSVC that will not run on heroku.

Comment: MSVC installed too @mpromonet, i re-install heroku, rust, but still shows the same.

Comment: @sunny9495: I was speaking about heroku cloud platform, not about your pc. heroku cloud platform use ubuntu, your pc run under windows (I guess from your answer). Did you try to remove pywinpty from the requirements.txt you used to push to heroku cloud platform ?

Comment: It worked mate..Thanks alot for the help mpromonet