# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: While deploying codes on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, rust

I am trying to deploy my flask application on the Heroku platform. I am completely new to this platform. I have made my requirements.txt using the command `pip freeze > requirements.txt` also created a Procfile that contain `web: gunicorn app:app`

When I am trying to deploy the code on Heroku the same error is showing (Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error') I have gone through the error message and as per the instruction I tried to install the rust package manager through the given link `https://rustup.rs/` but still the same error is showing.

Please help me to figure out what I am missing here.
Thanks in advance

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Python app detected
-----> No Python version was specified. Using the buildpack default: python-3.9.6
       To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
-----> Installing python-3.9.6
-----> Installing pip 20.2.4, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.36.2
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting absl-py==0.12.0
         Downloading absl_py-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (129 kB)
       Collecting altgraph==0.17
         Downloading altgraph-0.17-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
       Collecting anyio==2.2.0
         Downloading anyio-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
       Collecting argon2-cffi==20.1.0
         Downloading argon2_cffi-20.1.0-cp35-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (97 kB)
       Collecting async-generator==1.10
         Downloading async_generator-1.10-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
       Collecting attrs==20.3.0
         Downloading attrs-20.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (49 kB)
       Collecting autopep8==1.5.7
         Downloading autopep8-1.5.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (45 kB)
       Collecting Babel==2.9.1
         Downloading Babel-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.8 MB)
       Collecting backcall==0.2.0
         Downloading backcall-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
       Collecting beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
         Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.9.3-py3-none-any.whl (115 kB)
       Collecting bleach==3.3.0
         Downloading bleach-3.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (283 kB)
       Collecting blinker==1.4
         Downloading blinker-1.4.tar.gz (111 kB)
       Collecting cachetools==4.2.2
         Downloading cachetools-4.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
       Collecting catboost==0.25.1
         Downloading catboost-0.25.1-cp39-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (67.3 MB)
       Collecting category-encoders==2.2.2
         Downloading category_encoders-2.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (80 kB)
       Collecting certifi==2020.12.5
         Downloading certifi-2020.12.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)
       Collecting cffi==1.14.5
         Downloading cffi-1.14.5-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (406 kB)
       Collecting chardet==4.0.0
         Downloading chardet-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
       Collecting click==7.1.2
         Downloading click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
       Collecting colorama==0.4.4
         Downloading colorama-0.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
       Collecting comtypes==1.1.10
         Downloading comtypes-1.1.10.tar.gz (145 kB)
       Collecting cycler==0.10.0
         Downloading cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.5 kB)
       Collecting decorator==5.0.7
         Downloading decorator-5.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (8.8 kB)
       Collecting defusedxml==0.7.1
         Downloading defusedxml-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
       Collecting deprecation==2.1.0
         Downloading deprecation-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
       Collecting dnspython==2.1.0
         Downloading dnspython-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (241 kB)
       Collecting docopt==0.6.2
         Downloading docopt-0.6.2.tar.gz (25 kB)
       Collecting email-validator==1.1.3
         Downloading email_validator-1.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
       Collecting entrypoints==0.3
         Downloading entrypoints-0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
       Collecting et-xmlfile==1.1.0
         Downloading et_xmlfile-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.7 kB)
       Collecting Flask==1.1.2
         Downloading Flask-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
       Collecting Flask-Mail==0.9.1
         Downloading Flask-Mail-0.9.1.tar.gz (45 kB)
       Collecting Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
         Downloading Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
       Collecting Flask-WTF==0.15.1
         Downloading Flask_WTF-0.15.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
       Collecting future==0.18.2
         Downloading future-0.18.2.tar.gz (829 kB)
       Collecting fuzzywuzzy==0.18.0
         Downloading fuzzywuzzy-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
       Collecting gevent==21.1.2
         Downloading gevent-21.1.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (6.0 MB)
       Collecting google-auth==1.30.0
         Downloading google_auth-1.30.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (146 kB)
       Collecting google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.4
         Downloading google_auth_oauthlib-0.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
       Collecting graphviz==0.16
         Downloading graphviz-0.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
       Collecting greenlet==1.0.0
         Downloading greenlet-1.0.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (163 kB)
       Collecting grpcio==1.34.1
         Downloading grpcio-1.34.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (4.0 MB)
       Collecting gunicorn==20.1.0
         Downloading gunicorn-20.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
       Collecting h5py==3.1.0
         Downloading h5py-3.1.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (4.4 MB)
       Collecting idna==2.10
         Downloading idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
       Collecting imbalanced-learn==0.8.0
         Downloading imbalanced_learn-0.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (206 kB)
       Collecting imblearn==0.0
         Downloading imblearn-0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.9 kB)
       Collecting ipykernel==5.5.3
         Downloading ipykernel-5.5.3-py3-none-any.whl (120 kB)
       Collecting ipython==7.23.0
         Downloading ipython-7.23.0-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
       Collecting ipython-genutils==0.2.0
         Downloading ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
       Collecting itsdangerous==1.1.0
         Downloading itsdangerous-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
       Collecting jedi==0.18.0
         Downloading jedi-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)
       Collecting Jinja2==2.11.3
         Downloading Jinja2-2.11.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
       Collecting joblib==0.17.0
         Downloading joblib-0.17.0-py3-none-any.whl (301 kB)
       Collecting Js2Py==0.71
         Downloading Js2Py-0.71-py3-none-any.whl (1.0 MB)
       Collecting json5==0.9.5
         Downloading json5-0.9.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
       Collecting jsonschema==3.2.0
         Downloading jsonschema-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
       Collecting jupyter-client==6.1.12
         Downloading jupyter_client-6.1.12-py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
       Collecting jupyter-core==4.7.1
         Downloading jupyter_core-4.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
       Collecting jupyter-packaging==0.9.2
         Downloading jupyter_packaging-0.9.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
       Collecting jupyter-server==1.6.4
         Downloading jupyter_server-1.6.4-py3-none-any.whl (377 kB)
       Collecting jupyterlab==3.0.14
         Downloading jupyterlab-3.0.14-py3-none-any.whl (8.3 MB)
       Collecting jupyterlab-pygments==0.1.2
         Downloading jupyterlab_pygments-0.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.6 kB)
       Collecting jupyterlab-server==2.5.0
         Downloading jupyterlab_server-2.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (49 kB)
       Collecting keras-nightly==2.5.0.dev2021032900
         Downloading keras_nightly-2.5.0.dev2021032900-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
       Collecting Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
         Downloading Keras_Preprocessing-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
       Collecting kiwisolver==1.3.1
         Downloading kiwisolver-1.3.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (1.2 MB)
       Collecting lightgbm==3.2.1
         Downloading lightgbm-3.2.1-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.0 MB)
       Collecting Markdown==3.3.4
         Downloading Markdown-3.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
       Collecting MarkupSafe==1.1.1
         Downloading MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (32 kB)
       Collecting matplotlib==3.4.2
         Downloading matplotlib-3.4.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (10.3 MB)
       Collecting matplotlib-inline==0.1.2
         Downloading matplotlib_inline-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
       Collecting mistune==0.8.4
         Downloading mistune-0.8.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
       Collecting mysqlclient==2.0.3
         Downloading mysqlclient-2.0.3.tar.gz (88 kB)
       Collecting nbclassic==0.2.7
         Downloading nbclassic-0.2.7-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
       Collecting nbclient==0.5.3
         Downloading nbclient-0.5.3-py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
       Collecting nbconvert==6.0.7
         Downloading nbconvert-6.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (552 kB)
       Collecting nbformat==5.1.3
         Downloading nbformat-5.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
       Collecting nest-asyncio==1.5.1
         Downloading nest_asyncio-1.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (5.0 kB)
       Collecting notebook==6.3.0
         Downloading notebook-6.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (9.5 MB)
       Collecting numpy==1.19.4
         Downloading numpy-1.19.4-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (14.5 MB)
       Collecting oauthlib==3.1.0
         Downloading oauthlib-3.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)
       Collecting openpyxl==3.0.7
         Downloading openpyxl-3.0.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (243 kB)
       Collecting opt-einsum==3.3.0
         Downloading opt_einsum-3.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
       Collecting packaging==20.9
         Downloading packaging-20.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
       Collecting pandas==1.1.4
         Downloading pandas-1.1.4-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (9.3 MB)
       Collecting pandocfilters==1.4.3
         Downloading pandocfilters-1.4.3.tar.gz (16 kB)
       Collecting parso==0.8.2
         Downloading parso-0.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
       Collecting patsy==0.5.1
         Downloading patsy-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (231 kB)
       Collecting pefile==2021.5.24
         Downloading pefile-2021.5.24.tar.gz (66 kB)
       Collecting pickleshare==0.7.5
         Downloading pickleshare-0.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9 kB)
       Collecting Pillow==8.2.0
         Downloading Pillow-8.2.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (3.0 MB)
       Collecting pipwin==0.5.1
         Downloading pipwin-0.5.1.tar.gz (8.8 kB)
       Collecting plotly==4.14.3
         Downloading plotly-4.14.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13.2 MB)
       Collecting prometheus-client==0.10.1
         Downloading prometheus_client-0.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (55 kB)
       Collecting prompt-toolkit==3.0.18
         Downloading prompt_toolkit-3.0.18-py3-none-any.whl (367 kB)
       Collecting protobuf==3.17.0
         Downloading protobuf-3.17.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl (1.0 MB)
       Collecting py4j==0.10.9
         Downloading py4j-0.10.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (198 kB)
       Collecting pyasn1==0.4.8
         Downloading pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
       Collecting pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
         Downloading pyasn1_modules-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
       Collecting pycodestyle==2.7.0
         Downloading pycodestyle-2.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (41 kB)
       Collecting pycparser==2.20
         Downloading pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
       Collecting pygame==2.0.1
         Downloading pygame-2.0.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (11.8 MB)
       Collecting Pygments==2.9.0
         Downloading Pygments-2.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.0 MB)
       Collecting pyinstaller==4.4
         Downloading pyinstaller-4.4-py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.5 MB)
       Collecting pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2021.2
         Downloading pyinstaller_hooks_contrib-2021.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (190 kB)
       Collecting pyjsparser==2.7.1
         Downloading pyjsparser-2.7.1.tar.gz (24 kB)
       Collecting PyMySQL==1.0.2
         Downloading PyMySQL-1.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (43 kB)
       Collecting pyparsing==2.4.7
         Downloading pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
       Collecting pypiwin32==223
         Downloading pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 kB)
       Collecting PyPrind==2.11.3
         Downloading PyPrind-2.11.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.4 kB)
       Collecting pyrsistent==0.17.3
         Downloading pyrsistent-0.17.3.tar.gz (106 kB)
       Collecting pySmartDL==1.3.4
         Downloading pySmartDL-1.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
       Collecting pyspark==3.1.1
         Downloading pyspark-3.1.1.tar.gz (212.3 MB)
       Collecting python-dateutil==2.8.1
         Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
       Collecting pyttsx==1.1
         Downloading pyttsx-1.1.tar.gz (23 kB)
       Collecting pyttsx3==2.90
         Downloading pyttsx3-2.90-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
       Collecting pytz==2020.4
         Downloading pytz-2020.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (509 kB)
       Collecting pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
         Downloading pywin32_ctypes-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
       Collecting pywinpty==1.0.1
         Downloading pywinpty-1.0.1.tar.gz (47 kB)
         Installing build dependencies: started
         Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
         Getting requirements to build wheel: started
         Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
           Preparing wheel metadata: started
           Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
           ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
            command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpnij9ftxr
                cwd: /tmp/pip-install-w7oyrrfw/pywinpty
           Complete output (6 lines):
           Checking for Rust toolchain...
           
           Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.
           This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through
           the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/
           
           ----------------------------------------
       ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpnij9ftxr Check the logs for full command output.
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0):

It is having issues installing `pywinpty`...

```
   Collecting pywinpty==1.0.1
     Downloading pywinpty-1.0.1.tar.gz (47 kB)
     Installing build dependencies: started
     Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
     Getting requirements to build wheel: started
     Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
       Preparing wheel metadata: started
       Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
       ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
        command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpnij9ftxr
            cwd: /tmp/pip-install-w7oyrrfw/pywinpty
       Complete output (6 lines):
       Checking for Rust toolchain...
       
       Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.
       This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through
       the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/
```

Heroku is a PaaS, which means the code will not run on your local machine but rather in the "cloud" on a Linux VM, which would not allow you to install pywinpty.

See [Push rejected, fails Python App to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67394704/push-rejected-fails-python-app-to-heroku)